# User can see and enter the Wordpress Admin without login

Tags: wp-admin, security, admin-bar

I have some users reporting to me that they can see the admin bar and also they can enter the admin panel of the website without login in.

I'm not sure how this is possible and I'm trying to find a solution, but so far unsuccessfully.

Can anyone explain to me how is it possible and what can i do to avoid this?

Comment: Any chance your site caching isn't differentiating between logged in users and not logged in users, and so if a logged in user views a page then the version with the admin bar gets cached and served to all users?

Comment: But no this shouldn't be possible without a logged in cookie. Who does it say they're logged in as? Do they actually have the login cookies? Can you get them to tell you how to do this, and follow their steps in an incognito browser to replicate?

Comment: Do you have any authentication related plugins, or membership or message board or similar? Do you have a custom comment system that might be setting commenters up as full users? or anything like that

Comment: hi @Rup - the user didnt do anythign - he just went to the website and saw the bar on top of the website - its not a person that has ever heard about login or admin access or entered the admin panel.

Comment: @Rup I don't believe I do.

Comment: @PauloBrás Are you on WordPress.com? On WordPress.com sites you will see the admin bar any time you are logged in to WordPress.com. They can access the dashboard but all they will have access to is their profile.

Comment: @JacobPeattie this is not Wordpress.com development - it's a custom build. After some investigation it seems that the bar is visible but the access its not allowed - still doesn't answer the question of why the users are seeing the admin bar at all. I tested with multiple devices and indeed it shows, even in incognito.

Comment: Are you using a cache plugin/solution of some kind and not excluding logged in users?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes we are using WP-Optimize - Clean, Compress, Cache but we didnt do any custoization - I've assumed that it would handle users automatically.

Comment: You should contact its developers for support with this issue as a starting point. It's the most likely cause and there's simply not enough information for anybody to help here (and it's not really a development question, it's really a support question).

Comment: @JacobPeattie thank you very much for your support! As a security point, I wanted to double check with all sources possible. I will follow your advise and check with them. Thank you all.

Comment: @JacobPeattie can you post that as an answer?